# Steam: How retrieve game scheme data?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

CS:GO
https://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_730/GetSchema/v2/?key=1C3570A1EB59D14F4DEF3115651B811A&language=ru
TF2
https://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetSchema/v2/?key=1C3570A1EB59D14F4DEF3115651B811A&language=ru

but

DOTA2
https://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_570/GetSchema/v2/?key=1C3570A1EB59D14F4DEF3115651B811A&language=ru

is empty =(
{

}

Comment: Unsure what you're asking. Is your question *"Why when querying for DOTA2 is the response empty?"* - if so, we don't know. Contact steam?

Comment: I apologize. There is an official documentation. It says that the reference above should work, but it's not working. On the Internet, people write that has not worked for a very long time. But a bunch of sites continue to appear and update things. I am looking for where they can take these data. I have a project burns with a blue flame.

Answer (score 0):

There is a report on the API bug tracker about people getting empty returns on certain API calls which appears to be a user specific problem.

> This seems to be user specific, certain steam IDs I'm finding will just >completely fail and return a 503 with { } as the contents while others will >always succeed. This is an incredibly important API endpoint if you do anything > relating to automated trading as it's the only way to get the original_id of an > item. --BenWoodford (talk) 16:50, 5 June 2015 (UTC)

Alternatively, you ca, make an API call to the schemaURL and fetch the schema in text file.
https://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_570/GetSchemaURL/v1//?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&language=XX

This will return you with a simple response:

```
{
    "result": {
        "status": 1,
        "items_game_url": "http://cdn.dota2.com/apps/570/scripts/items/items_game.850380e4e0cd6141655d46735fa4548570167393.txt"
    }
}
```

To get a decent overview on the Steam API's, you can always have a look at:  https://lab.xpaw.me/steam_api_documentation.html